# Arithmetic operations using OOP

Tags: c++, oop, math

I want to create a program where the user will input his answer to the following questions and the program will check whether his answer is good or not. But i am getting an error 
operations::calculations must return a value.
I have the following queries:
1.How do I remove this error?
2. Have I written my OOP code the correct way?
3. Is there another way I can write this code more efficiently?

My codes are shown below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class operations {
    int res1,res2,r_a,r_b;

public:
    operations();
    operations(int  r1, int r2,int ra, int rb,);
    int calculations();
    int display();
    ~operations();
};
operations::operations() {
    res1 = 0;
    res2 = 0;
    r_a = 0;
    r_b = 0;
}
operations::operations(int r1, int r2,int ra, int rb, int rc) {
    res1 = r1;
    res2 = r2;
    r_a = ra;
    r_b = rb;
}

int operations::calculations() {
    cout << "Complete the following." << endl;

    cout << "(a) 34 + 5 = ";
    res1 = 34 + 5;
    cin >> r_a;
    if (r_a != res1)
        cout << "Wrong! The correct answer is " << res1 << endl;
    else
        cout << "Correct!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "(b) 56 + 702 = ";
    res2 = 56 + 702;
    cin >> r_b;

    if (r_b != res2)
        cout << "Wrong! The correct answer is " << res2 << endl;
    else
        cout << "Correct" << endl;
}
int operations::display(){
    int basic;
    basic = calculations();
    return basic;
}
operations::~operations() {
}
int main() {
    operations o;
    o.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You said `calculations` must return an `int`, but you are not returning anything from the function.

Comment: im returning res1 and res2 together with the string...should i use void instead of int?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.